# mySQL - Reiteratively Count rows that have particular CSV string

Tags: mysql

2-column MySQL Table:

```
| id| class   |
|---|---------|
| 1 | A,B     |
| 2 | B,C,D   |  
| 3 | C,D,A,G |
| 4 | E,F,G   |
| 5 | A,F,G   |
| 6 | E,F,G,B |
```

Requirement is to generate a report/output which tells which individual CSV value of `class` column is in how many rows.

For example, `A` is present in 3 rows (with id `1,3,5`), and `C` is present in 2 rows (with id `2,3`), and `G` is in 4 rows (`3,4,5,6`) so the output report should be

```
A - 3
B - 3
C - 2
...
...
G - 4
```

Essentially, column `id` can be ignored.

The draft that I can think of - first all the values of `class` column need to picked, split on comma, then create a distinct list of each unique value (`A,B,C...`), and then count how many rows contain the unique value from that distinct list.
While I know basic SQL queries, this is way too complex for me. Am unable to match it with some CSV split function in MySQL. (Am new to SQL so don't know much).

An alternative approach I made it to work - Download class column values in a file, feed it to a perl script which will create a distinct array of A,B,C, then read the downloaded CSV file again foreach element in distinct array and increase the count, and finally publish the report. But this is in perl which will be a separate execution, while the client needs it in SQL report.

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: strong values as csv is very bad database design

Comment: Get rid of this CSV design and instead place each CSV value onto a separate row.  If you have the ability to change your table design, you should go in this direction.  Only stick with the question above if you can't change it, or maybe if this is homework.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - this is a pretty old db design of a client. Can't change it unfortunately.

Comment: Also, it is a local db, where the report will be executed frequently on a local network. So complexity and long-time taken is not an issue for the client.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [split-string-into-rows](https://gist.github.com/duanehutchins/c6000b367b3032b0b495c46b3bc370c8) function to get distinct values and use COUNT function to find number of occurrences. Specifically [check here](https://gist.github.com/duanehutchins/c6000b367b3032b0b495c46b3bc370c8?permalink_comment_id=4047310#gistcomment-4047310)